# What terraform command to use to check the resource creation status?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-template-file

We are using terraform to create the resources in aws cloud. 
Once the `terraform apply` is run our resources are getting created in the cloud.
However we want to come back and again at a later point in time and check the status of the resources created as a part of the current terraform template.

What will be the command to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

Could you maybe explain the purpose in more detail?

However just going off your original post, you most likely want `terraform show`?

List of all the Terraform commands: https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/index.html

You would also be able to see these if you just type `terraform` into the command line :)